# Importing a go package from github that uses native C code

Tags: go

I'm writing some code that needs access to a Cobra CLI object from another GitHub repo:

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/spf13/cobra/doc"
    "github.com/sylabs/singularity/cmd/singularity/cli"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    err := doc.GenReSTTree(cli.SingularityCmd, "./")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

I also have the following version constraint:

```
[[constraint]]
  name = "github.com/sylabs/singularity"
  version = "3.0.3"
```

Now, when I `go install`, I get the error:

```
# github.com/TMiguelT/singularity-userdocs/vendor/github.com/sylabs/singularity/internal/pkg/runtime/engines/config/starter
vendor/github.com/sylabs/singularity/internal/pkg/runtime/engines/config/starter/starter.go:10:10: fatal error: starter.h: No such file or directory
 #include "starter.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

So when I try to build my code, it tries to compile the singularity module and fails because it can't find some C code. This header file is located here in the repo I'm importing: https://github.com/sylabs/singularity/blob/v3.0.3/cmd/starter/c/starter.h

How can I make my `go install` aware of this, to ensure my project compiles?

Comment: Have you tried to no use dep/glide (??) but just checkout github.com/sylabs/singularity in GOPATH in the right version and compile/install it there instead of your vendored copy? What is the output if you run go build with -x?

Comment: removing `unused-packages` prune option may solve the problem: https://github.com/golang/dep/issues/1731 , however, singularity uses [their own build script](https://github.com/sylabs/singularity/blob/master/INSTALL.md#compile-the-singularity-binary) to build, so including this project as dependency will be very hard job.

Comment: @ymonad Well, that did get me past that particular error and onto the next (you might be right about struggling to include it as a dependency). But if you post this as an answer I'm happy to accept it